# Proof that $F(a)\approx F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field

I'm reading a proof of the theorem that $F(a)$ is isomorphic to $ F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ in the book called *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian, and I don't understand some key elements of the proof [I think this book is too confusing in numerous places in the sections on rings and fields, but it was clear and straightforward on groups]. Here are the theorem and the proof:

[image]

Here's what I do not understand:

**(1)** If $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$ and $\ker \phi\ne F[x]$, then how does it follow from the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings and the corollary (below) that $\phi(F[x])$is a subfield of $F(a)$?

[image]

**(2)** When the author writes that

> $\phi(F[x])$ contains both $F$ and $a$ and recalling that $F(a)$ is the smallest such field ...

what does he refer to by "the smallest such field"? The smallest *what* field?

**(3)** Can't one immediately see the image of $\phi$ is indeed $F(a)$, just by definition? $\phi$ takes all polynomials in $F[x]$ and evaluates them at $a$. I don't understand the author's argument at all.

**(4)** The author also writes that

[image]

But isn't the basis for $F(a)$ one-dimensional, after all?

Sorry for the long message. Would really appreciate your help in understanding this proof. In my opinion the author is skipping too many details. In my university, I'd get reduced marks for unproved statements like "clearly, [...]".

Comment: $F(a)$ is a $F$-vector space, this is what we are going to prove, by showing that $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a field (and obviously a $F$-vector space) and that $\phi : F[x]/(p(x)) \to F[a]$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with $\phi(c) = 0 \implies c= 0$ so that it is an isomorphism. Hence $F[a]$ is a field, i.e. $F[a] = F(a)$.

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean by "$F$-vector space"?

Comment: If $F$ is a field then $F^d$ is a $d$-dimensional $F$-vector space. Here $F[a] = \{ \sum_{n=0}^{d-1} c_n a^n, c_n \in F\}$ is a $d$-dimensional $F$-vector space, where $d = deg(p)$. And since we are proving $F[a]$ is a field, we get $F[a] = F(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$. According to Theorem 17.5, $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$. According to Corollary 1, $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field. But $\ker{\phi}=\langle p(x)\rangle$. According to the First Isomorphism Theorem of Rings, $\phi(F[x])\cong F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, showing that the image of $\phi$ is a subfield of $F(a)$.

**(2)** $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing both $F$ and $a$ by definition (see the discussion above the Definition in page 340).

**(3)** Yes, and the author proved it easly as you say (end of first paragraph). But since the image of $\phi$ is $F(a)$, it follows from the result in **(1)** that $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\cong F(a)$

**(4)** Why do you think that $F(a)$ is one-dimensional? Is it because you see it as a vector space over itself? $\mathbb{C}$ is one dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, but $2$-dimensional as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Even $\mathbb{R}$ can be infinite dimensional if you consider it as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. $F(a)$ is surely one dimensional as a vector space over itself, like any field. But over $F$, that's not the case because $a\notin F$ (otherwise $p(x)$ wouldn't be irreducible), but given the way any element can be expressed in $F(a)$ as shown in the theorem, the dimension of $F(a)$ as a vector space over $F$ is exactly the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: (1) How do we know that $F(a)$ is a field, in the first place?
(2) I'm confused between $F(a)$ and $F[a]$. Isn't $F(a)$ an evaluation of all polynomials in $F[x]$ at $a$? Everything points out that it is so. But $F[a]$ is a set like $\{ x+ay: x, y\in F, a\in E\text{ where E is an extension field of F } \}$. So, this is really confusing.

(3) Why does one need to prove what is true by definition? And the way the author proves seems to be unclear; i.e. I don't see how his notion about the smallest field leads to believe that Im$\phi=F(a)$.

Comment: (1) You should know what things are before moving on to their properties. Always refer to definitions. According to the paragraph right above the definition in page 340, $F(a)$ is by **definition** the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$. In particular, it is a field.
(2) Concerning $F[a]$, that's just an error. I meant $F(a)$, not $F[a]$. Now, concerning what you said "Isn't $F(a)$ an evaluation of all polynomials in $F[x]$ at $a$?" The answer is yes; in fact that's the meaning of $\phi(F[x])=F(a)$. But by **definition** in your book, $F(a)$ is THE smallest field containing $F$ and $a$...

Comment: ... It turns out that that's the same thing as shown in the theorem. (3) One doesn't prove what's a definition, that's right? But as I said, by **definition**, $F(a)$ is *the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$*. So, the obvious fact that $F(a)=\phi(F[x])$ is not a definition, so it should be proven. $\phi$ is a map from $F[x]$ to $F(a)$ given by $\phi(f(x))=f(a)$. It makes sense, i.e, for any $f(x)\in F[x]$, $f(a)$ is indeed in $F(a)$ because it is a sum and products of elements in $F\subset F(a)$ and $a\in F(a)$. Hence, $\text{Im}\phi\subset F(a)$. Why equality holds?...

Comment: ... To show equality, we can show that $F(a)\subset\text{Im}\phi$, right? What does it mean that $F(a)$ is the **smallest* field containing $F$ and $a$? It means the following: "For any field $K$ such that $F\subset K$ and $a\in K$, we have $F(a)\subset K$". As shown in (1), $\text{Im}\phi$ is a subfield of $F(a)$. In particular, $\text{Im}\phi$ is a field. Furthermore, it contains $F$ and $a$. One has $F\subset\text{Im}\phi$ because for any $g\in F$, let $f(x)=g\in F[x]$. Then $f(a)=g\in\text{Im}\phi$. One also has $a\in\text{Im}\phi$ because for $f(x)=x\in F[x]$, $f(a)=a\in\text{Im}\phi$...

Comment: ...Thus $\text{Im}\phi$ is a field containing $F$ and $a$. By definition of $F(a)$, we have $F(a)\subset\text{Im}\phi$. Combining this with $\text{Im}\phi\subset F(a)$, we conclude that $F(a)=\text{Im}\phi$. If you have another question, feel free to ask it, @sequence . But make sure you understand the definitions of things ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Scientifica. So, is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$ defined as $F(a) = \{ \frac{g(a)}{h(a)}: g(x), h(x)\in F[x], a\not\in F\}$? (@DonAntonio in this thread gave just this definition). But why is this definition justified? I guess we have that $F(a)$ is not just evaluation at $a$, strictly speaking, because $a\not\in F$. This definition seems to be justified because we need $F(a)$ to be a field, and thus we need to get all inverses into collection, if I'm right.

Comment: Also, the book says that $F(a)$ and $F[a]$ are equivalent, the difference being the emphasis on the fact that $F(a)$ is a field, while $F[a]$ is more common in the context of rings (not necessarily fields). But in some sense $F(a)$ remains to look like evaluation at $a$, so if I were them, I would prefer the notation to be less ambiguous, and $F[x]$ would be OK with me.

Comment: You're welcome @sequence :) Well you should know that in mathematics, some things can have many definitions, but all of which are equivalent, i.e, if you have two statements that represents definitions of something, the two are said to be equivalent definitions if when you consider the definition as one of them, you can prove that what's stated in the other holds. In your case, you gave two **different** definitions of $F(a)$: One is "the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$". The other is $F(a)=\left\{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}\mid g(x),h(x)\in F[x]\right\}...$

Comment: ... Of course having different definitions that lead to different things is nonsense to us, right? Proving that two definitions are **equivalent** means that there's no problem, as they mean the same thing. Let's go ahead. First, let us use the second definition. $F(a)=\left\{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}\mid g(x),h(x)\in F[x]\right\}$. So, let's show that $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$. I guess it's clear that $F(a)$ is a field and, obviously, it contains $F$ and $a$. Now why is it the smallest such? Well, let $K$ be any field containing $F$ and $a$. Let's show that $F(a)\subset K$.

Comment: To do so, we show that any element of $F(a)$ is in $K$. So, consider $\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}$ in $F(a)$ where $g(x),h(x)\in F[x]$. $g(a)$ is an expression involving sums and multiplications of elements in $F$ and $a$. Since $K$ is a field containing $F$ and $a$, we have $g(a)\in K$. The same argument applies to $h(a)$. As $K$ is a field, $h(a)$ has an inverse and thus $\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}\in K$ as desired. Now, we should use the first definition and prove that $F(a)=\left\{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}\mid g(x),h(x)\in F[x]\right\}$. To avoid repetition, let...

Comment: ...$K=\left\{\frac{g(a)}{h(a)}\mid g(x),h(x)\in F[x]\right\}$. Clearly, $K$ is a field containing $F$ and $a$. Since $F(a)$ is defined as the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$, we have $F(a)\subset K$. For the other implication, you can simply use again the same argument as above to show that $K$ is included in $F(a)$. There's some repetition when proving this equivalence, right? Actually I made it too hard because in your case, we don't really have to go through proving equivalence but rather equality (I must be tired this night hhh) because your two **different** definitions are ...

Comment: ... in fact two different ways to consider $F(a)$. If we show that they are equal, we're actually done, and that's what we showed n the first part of the proof. Now for your remark "This definition seems to be justified because we need $F(a)$ to be a field, and thus we need to get all inverses into collection, if I'm right.". You're right; in order for $F(a)$ to be a field, inverses should exist. However, you should believe in the proven theorem: the elements of $F(a)$ can all be written in the simpler form $f(a)$ where $f(x)\in F[x]$ with degree $n-1=\deg{p(x)}-1$. So, this means that...

Comment: ... for $f(x)\in F[x]$, one has $\exists g(x)\in F[x],\, \frac{1}{f(a)}=g(a)$, or, $f(a)g(a)=1$, if $f(a)\neq 0$. This theorem can be used to prove this fact. You can also convince yourself in a different way: since $f(a)\neq 0$ and $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, then $f(x)$ and $p(x)$ are relatively prime, i.e, their greatest common division is the polynomial $1$. According to Bezout's Theorem, there exists $g(x),u(x)\in F[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x)+p(x)u(x)=1$. Since $p(a)=0$, it follows that $f(a)g(a)=1$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks again, @Scientifica, for your detailed and clear explanations. Does your last comment mean that any $f(a)$ is divisible by any $g(a)$ in $F(a)$? That is, if we can express any $\frac{h(a)}{i(a)}\in F(a)$ as $g(a)$, then $i(a)$ divides $h(a)$? Also, how do you deduce that $\deg f(x) = \deg p(x)-1$?

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't mean that. What I meant is that any element of the form $\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$ is in $F(a)$ in the sense that it can be written in fhe form $c_0+\dots c_{n-1}a^{n-1}$ because $\frac{1}{g(a)}$, the inverse of $g(a)$, is actually the value of a polynomial at $a$ (the proof using Bezout's Theorem). But yes good remark. Since there exists $q(x)\in F[x]$ such that $\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}=q(a)$, or in other words $f(a)=g(a)q(a)$, it means that any $g(a)$ divides any $f(a)$...

Comment: ...For the degree, I didn't deduce anything. I said that any element $k\in F(a)$ can be written in the form $k=f(a)$ for (in fact a unique) $f(x)\in F[x]$ such that $\deg{p(x)}\le \deg{p(x)}-1$ (not necessarily equal; I'm self-thought in abstract algebra so don't give me 100% credibility). For "how do you deduce that", well, that's what your theorem is about. I believe that you should look at a particular example to feel this theorem, for example $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ where $p(x)=x^2-2$...

Comment: ...Note that $a\sqrt{2}+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ has an inverse of the form described earlier, and that's pretty easy: $\frac{1}{a\sqrt{2}+b}=\frac{a\sqrt{2}-b}{2a^2-b^2}=\frac{a}{2a^2-b^2}\sqrt{2}-\frac{b}{2a^2-b^2}$ (the denominator never vanishes because $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 0):

(1) The First isomorphism theorem tells you that $\;F[x]/\ker\phi\cong\phi(F[x])\;$ , and corollary 1 tells you that $\;F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\;$ is a field whenever $\;p(x)\;$ is irreducible. Both things, together with $\;\ker\phi=\langle p(x)\rangle\;$ gives you the result you ask about.

(2) Smallest such field" means here " the smallest field containing both $\;F\;$ and $\;a\;$" .

(3) Well, by its mere definition, $\;\phi(g(x)):=g(a)\;$ , so $\;\phi(F[x])=F[a]\;$ . Yet, as $\;a\;$ is algebraic over $\;F\;$ , we have that $\;F[a]=F(a)\;$ and we're done.

Comment: For (1), the problem is that it is not obvious that $\phi(F[x])$ is a subfield of $F(a)$ from the corollary and the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings. Can you please explain how exactly it may follow so?
$$ $$

For (2), how do we know that $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$? I don't think this is obvious. I.e., how do we know that $F(a)$ actually contains $F$?

$$$$
For (3), Sorry, didn't understand. What does it mean to say "algebraic over"? This is upcoming in the book, but it's not been covered up to the page I'm reading.

Comment: @sequence What isn't clear? I think you may be missing some details: The FIT tells you the first isomorphism. That much must be clear. And now the corollary gives you that the left hand (and thus the right one, too) in that isomorphism is a field. (2) That is the **definition** of that, but you can also almost trivially prove it: **any** field containing both $\;F,a\;$ **must** contain *any* rational function over $\;F\;$ in $\;a\;$ , i.e.: $\;F(a)\;$ ...If you don't know what is "algebraic element" then I think you're attempting something you're still not ready for.

Comment: Cont. :  "An element $\;a\;$ is algebraic over a field $\;F\;$ " means there existis $\;0\neq p(x)\in F[x]\;$ s.t. $\;p(a)=0\;$ .

Comment: (1) Im $\phi$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, that is clear. That Im $\phi$ is a field is also clear. But it's not clear why $\phi(F[x])$ must be a subfield of $F(a)$. I don't see how this follows from the preceding.

(2) How do you prove that any field containing $F$ and $a$ must contain any rational function over $F$ in $a$?

For algebraic elements, this has not yet been covered in the book (up to and including the page I'm reading on). So the author must be assuming something that has been covered so far, I believe.

@DonAntonio

Comment: @sequence Definition: $\;F(a):=\left\{\,\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}\;/\;p(x),\,q(x)\in F[x]\;,\;\;q(a)\neq0\,\right\}\;$ , and since $\;\phi(h(x)):=h(a)\;$ , I think the inclusion is now clear...

Comment: (2) Any field containing some elements contain all their products, sums, quotients ,etc. **as far as no division by zero** is done. Since any element of form $\;p(a)/q(a)\;$ is a quotient of sums and products of powers of $\;a\;$ times elements in $\;f\;$ ,each such quotient is in $\;F(a)\;$ as long as $\;q(a)\neq0\;$

Comment: About algebraic elements. Forget it in the meantime. It seems to be Gallian goes its own way in this. What you know is that $\;\phi(F(x))\subset F(a)\;$ and the former is a **field**, and since it contains $\;F,\,a\;$ it must also contain $\;F(a)\;$ , so you have a double opposite inclusion and thus an equality

Comment: The author of the book didn't give this kind of definition, and this definition appears to be quite weird, since it would make much more sense to think of $\phi(f(x))= f(a)$ as evaluation of $f$ at $a$, not at $\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}$, thus $F(a)$ would be intuitively thought of as the field of all polynomials $f$ evaluated at $a$, not some rational functions evaluated at $a$. I don't see how otherwise $\phi$ makes any sense.   @DonAntonio

Comment: @sequence **Any** polynomial in $\;a\;$ is trivially a rational function in $\;a\;$ !! The map is $\;f(x)\mapsto f(a)=\frac{f(a)}1\;$ , where the denominator is the polynomial $\;q(x)\equiv 1\;$ ,and thus $\;q(a)=1\;$ ...!

Comment: You're right, the definition does make sense, I just hadn't seen it anywhere before. So, $F(a)$, then, is a fractional field of $F[a]$, correct? Also, because $F(a)$ is the minimal field containing both $F$ and $a$, how does it follow that Im$(\phi) = F(a)$? @DonAntonio

Comment: How do you conclude that a field containing $F$ and $a$ contains $F(a)$?  @DonAntinio

Comment: @sequence I think we shall stop this as it is already too long. Again, Im$\,\phi\;$ is a field as it is isomorphic with $\;F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ and $\;f(x)\;$ is irreducible, thus the ideal $\;\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is maximal in $\;F[x]\;$ and **any** commutative unitary ring divided by a maximal ideal is a field. Since im$\,\phi\;$ is a field **and** contains $\;F,a\;$ it thus contains $\;F(a)\;$ , which is the minimal *such field*. Since the other inclusion is true (by the last comments...), we have equality.